# How to write a MongoDB $slice in golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

How do I write $slice MongoDB code in golang? Here is my MongoDB code:

```
db.userdetail.aggregate([{"$project":{"user":{"$slice":["$user",2,1]}}}]).pretty()
```

I try to write this code in golang:

```
o1 := bson.M{
        "$project":bson.M{"user":bson.M{"$slice":bson.M["$user",2,1,],},},
    }
```

It gives me the following err: `syntax error: unexpected comma, expecting ]`

Comment: Did my answer resolve the issue?

Comment: @ Chetan Kumar  Please respond so that other people can benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bson.M is map[string]interface not slice. And you need []interface for "$slice".

```
o1 := bson.M{"$project": bson.M{"user": bson.M{"$slice": []interface{}{"$user", 2, 1}}}}
```

If you share some dummy data, input and output, I could help you further.